# How to check EditText length and if it's more that "X" put the full text to another EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Actually i have two EditText in my app,

The first get the BarCode from the Scanner the second quantity.

But i have to do that if i'm in qta EditText and the length is > that 4 i will recognize it as a barcode and i will put that in the barcode EditText.

I was trying by setting an onFocus change but that wasn't working, and i've even tried with TextWatched onTextChange to check the qta edittext lenght > 4 but that was putting just 4 numbers in to barcode EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Focus Change event not Text Change Event. Because Text Change will be triggering for every text change.

You can try following snippet if onFocus change event is not working

your activity should  implement OnFocusChangeListener. That way, all your changes will be on that one method but you will have to check which view changed focus by getting the view id with v.getId() and handle accordingly.

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
   if(!hasFocus)
    {
      switch(v.getId()){
        case r.id.editText1:
          //TODO:your_logic_goes_here
        break;
      }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in using TextChangedListener here :

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length()>4){
                editTextBarCode.setText(s.toString());
            }else {
                //else you can set it to the same edit text or whatever you want
            }
        }
    });
```